# Is it possible to set transition speed/time in transition everywhere on android

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I'm using [Transitions-Everywhere](https://github.com/andkulikov/Transitions-Everywhere) for my app, and I wonder if I can set the transition speed/time of the transitions..

I have something like this:

```
TransitionManager().beginDelayedTransition(animLayout, new ChangeBounds());

FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) findViewById(R.id.myId).getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = (int) myHeight;
layoutParams.width = (int) myWidth;
myLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

In short, I want the transition to be slower than the default, but I just can't figure out how to set the speed of the transition!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can set the duration on the `Transition` you pass into `beginDelayedTransition()`. In your case that would be `ChangeBounds`. So try something like this:

```
final ChangeBounds transition = new ChangeBounds();
transition.setDuration(600L); // Sets a duration of 600 milliseconds
TransitionManager().beginDelayedTransition(animLayout, transition);
```

---

By default if no duration is set a `Transition` falls back to the default animation duration which is 300ms. So for example if you want the transition to take twice as long, use 600ms.

Comment: exactly what i needed, thanks a lot, by the way i did looked at some animation classes in the library but couldn't find the setDuration method, mind telling me where can i look it, i'm new to programming and open source so still grasping in reading libraries..

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        this.defaultPeekHeight = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels / 4
        bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight = defaultPeekHeight
        presenter.loadItems()
    }

    override fun onItemsLoaded(
        items: List<RecyclerItem<*>>
    ) {
        updateItems(items)
        b.root.doOnLayout {
            //animate expanding of bottom sheet
            val transition = ChangeBounds()
            transition.duration = ANIMATION_DURATION
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(b.draggableBottomSheetLayout, transition)
            bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight = max(b.root.height, defaultPeekHeight)
        }}
```